# How do I disconnect my OpenID (Google Apps) from my IMDB Account?

Tags: account-management, openid, imdb

Recently I signed up for IMDb. For this I used my Google Apps Account (Gmail) as an OpenID.

I have since come to the conclusion that having all these accounts connected is not a good idea, so I want to disconnect my IMDb account from my OpenID (Gmail) account. I have already changed the password on IMDb and I am able to login with the e-mail address (of the OpenID account) and the new password. Unfortunately I can still use OpenID to log in, too.

**So, how can I disconnect my OpenID account from my IMDB account?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this [Google Account Settings](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en) page (if the link doesn't work, you get there [via this link](https://www.google.com/settings/security)) you can deauthorize IMDB from accessing your Google data so stopping you to log on with your account.

Although this method blocks access from IMDB to Google, I think the reference to your account in IMDB will persist. There should be an option in their account settings as well to remove the association between that Google account and your IMDB account. I think that option does not exist, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've given your Google permission to IMDb, Logout. Now, try logging into IMDb using the usual IMDb login screen, enter your Gmail email address and then click on "Forgot password"

They'll send you a link on your Gmail account, click on it, change the password as desired.
Now, login through that new password and email address you have.

Go to https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/loggedin and click on delete account.
Enter the new password and delete the IMDB account! Now, revoke your Google access for IMDb again!